# My MacBook Pro (2010) beeps 3 times and not starting up

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I love this Macbook and I know its still in good condition. 3 beeps on start up and keeps beeping 3 times. Can start it up. Tried the press Command Option PR and turn on. didnt work.

some were saying its the RAM. need to upgrade.

currently its 4GB (two 2GB SO-DIMMs) of 1066MHz DDR3 memory; two SO-DIMM slots support up to 8GB.

Should I upgrade to 8GB?

or is it another issue that I am not aware of?

Apple support a bit under the weather.

So anyone has a theory on this?

need to start this one up so I can make sure all that is important has been saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about the problem on [Apple's Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202768).

The described behaviour definitely points to a memory (RAM) issue.

You can try to remove one memory stick and verify which one is the faulty one. You can then replace it with a new/working stick or upgrade. While different brands *may* work it is rather unlikely and one should always use the exact same memory model (watch [LTT's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTS0ybQ3lCI) about it).
Depending on the workload you may experience performance improvements by upgrading to faster and/or more RAM.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response . yes I saw that. but was wondering if there was possibly any other causes. Btw any recommended RAMs brand?

Comment: @OldGeek yes, buy quality memory.

Comment: @OldGeek Crucial is good though there are other good ones as well. You can check which Crucial memory models could be installed on your computer from [this page](https://www.crucial.com/upgrades/apple/macbook-pro-systems) on Crucial's web site. You can also check the technical specifications of your MBP including the memory it works on from [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en_US/specs).